# Get to data without touch access

Tags: adb, data-recovery

The screen of my Nexus 4 has a crack and touch is not working anymore. I'd like to get to some of my data using adb, but can't authorize it because I can't click/touch the authorization dialog.

Is there a way to authorize adb without touch access?

Is there another way to get to the data? It's a rooted phone and can boot into ClockworkMod Recovery

Answer (score 0):

You have luck that you have a rooted phone with CWM!

You can enable USB-OTG by applying this patch to your phone:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/orig-development/usb-otg-externally-powered-usb-otg-t2181820

Then you can plug a mouse and/or a keyboard and control your phone with it.